# Change font of a Table Header Section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Can anyone help me with the code missing in `viewForHeaderInSection`?

Do I have to create a UILabel?

What exactly should be done to change the font of the Table Header Section?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return 55.0;//Choose your custom row height
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.hoursArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView {

    //Code missing!

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    return self.hoursArray[section]
}
```

Comment: Please do not post code as an image. Please [edit] your question with the text of the code. Images can't be referenced or searched.

Comment: Ok, I just edited!

Comment: Don't update your question with an answer. If you found your own answer, post an actual answer below. If one of the other answers helped you, accept that answer instead.

Comment: Accepted the answer of bilal, but your answer was helpful too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this function and it should work with default label.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView {


}
```

For custom header, You can return any view here is an example of a UIlabel.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView {
    let label = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 30))
    label.textColor = UIColor.red
    label.text = self.hoursArray[section]
    return label
}
```

Comment: But how can I change the font of the Section Header e.g. from default to Times New Roman?

Comment: Why the `.init`? Just use `UILabel(frame: ...)`.

Comment: Just used to use init... Yeah without init better.

Answer (score 2):

Do not implement both `viewForHeaderInSection` and `titleForHeaderInSection`. If you want a custom view for the header, just implement the `viewForHeaderInSection` method. And you also need to implement the `heightForHeaderInSection` otherwise the header won't appear.

Typically you create, setup, and return an instance of `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` but you can also simply create a `UILabel` setup as desired.

Comment: Thanks, really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView 
{
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 30)
label.text = "I'am a test label"
label.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: label.font.pointSize)
return label
}
```